# CSS transition doesn't work properly after a function executes

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a transition that modifies the background color of a div when I hover the mouse over it and if I press the button that executes myFunction2 that also changes the background color of the div before hovering on the div, then the transition will not modify the background color anymore.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function myFunction() {   document.getElementById("myDIV").style.WebkitTransition = "all 2s"; // Code for Safari 3.1 to 6.0
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transition = "all 2s";     // Standard syntax
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 270px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    #myDIV:hover {
      background-color: coral;
      width: 570px;
      height: 500px;
      padding: 100px;
      border-radius: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Mouse over the DIV element and it will change, both in color and size!</p>
    <p>Click the "Try it" button and mouse over the DIV element again. The change will now happen gradually, like an animation:</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it2</button><br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>  
    <div id="myDIV">
      <h1>myDIV</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? What are you expecting the code to do?

Comment: I would expect the code to still change the background color even after it was changed by myFunction2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In myFunction2() u r setting the background color of the div to yellow so it is not changing (ie  the transition will not modify the background color anymore)

if you want to have transition then add transition through js itself.

DEMO:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 270px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#myDIV:hover {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 570px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Mouse over the DIV element and it will change, both in color and size!</p>

<p>Click the "Try it" button and mouse over the DIV element again. The change will now happen gradually, like an animation:</p>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it2</button>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <h1>myDIV</h1>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction2()
{
 document.getElementById("myDIV").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
var css = '#myDIV:hover{ background-color: yellow !important;}';
var style = document.createElement('style');
if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
}



function myFunction() {
var css = '#myDIV:hover{ background-color: coral !important;}';
var style = document.createElement('style');
if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.WebkitTransition = "all 2s"; // Code for Safari 3.1 to 6.0
  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transition = "all 2s";     // Standard syntax
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```